# How can use Uwsgi? where is my python home path?

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu

I'm trying to deploy my django app with ec2. and I follow some instruction.

but when I try to connect Uwsgi and my django app, there is a problem

```
(unifolio-back) ubuntu@ip-172-31-37-172:~$ which python
/home/ubuntu/.local/share/virtualenvs/unifolio-back-_HCbnSkq/bin/python

(unifolio-back) ubuntu@ip-172-31-37-172:~$ uwsgi --http :8080 --home /home/ubuntu/.local/share/virtualenvs/unifolio-back-_HCbnSkq/bin/python --chdir /srv/unifolio-back/ -w mysite.wsgi
*** Starting uWSGI 2.0.19.1 (64bit) on [Sat Dec 19 09:54:26 2020] ***
compiled with version: 7.5.0 on 19 December 2020 01:14:28
os: Linux-5.4.0-1029-aws #30~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 20 11:09:25 UTC 2020
nodename: ip-172-31-37-172
machine: x86_64
clock source: unix
detected number of CPU cores: 1
current working directory: /home/ubuntu
detected binary path: /home/ubuntu/.local/share/virtualenvs/unifolio-back-_HCbnSkq/bin/uwsgi
!!! no internal routing support, rebuild with pcre support !!!
chdir() to /srv/unifolio-back/
*** WARNING: you are running uWSGI without its master process manager ***
your processes number limit is 3802
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
detected max file descriptor number: 1024
lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
uWSGI http bound on :8080 fd 4
spawned uWSGI http 1 (pid: 2408)
uwsgi socket 0 bound to TCP address 127.0.0.1:40925 (port auto-assigned) fd 3
Python version: 3.6.9 (default, Oct  8 2020, 12:12:24)  [GCC 8.4.0]
!!! Python Home is not a directory: /home/ubuntu/.local/share/virtualenvs/unifolio-back-_HCbnSkq/bin/python !!!
Set PythonHome to /home/ubuntu/.local/share/virtualenvs/unifolio-back-_HCbnSkq/bin/python
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'
Current thread 0x00007f54d0d2a600 (most recent call first):
Aborted (core dumped)
```

what is the problem? I guess there is something wrong with python path... but I can't fine the way to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu's uses `uwsgi`'s plugin based architecture. In order to successfully run a Python 3 application, you need the `uwsgi-plugin-python3` plugin. First, install it with `apt`:

```
$ sudo apt install uwsgi-plugin-python3
```

Then, change your `uwsgi` command to the following:

```
uwsgi --http :8080 --virtualenv /home/ubuntu/.local/share/virtualenvs/unifolio-back-_HCbnSkq \
      --chdir /srv/unifolio-back/ -w mysite.wsgi --plugins python3
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Mac, install uwsgi using homebrew and use it.

```
$ brew install uwsgi

$ where uwsgi
/Users/chillaranand/homebrew/bin/uwsgi
```